# Change UI button color in MRTK for hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

[Scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juUaG.png)I need some help in making a simple prototype for Hololens.

I have 9 UI near interaction touchable buttons in scene like mobile keypad. I want them to highlight one by one randomly. I will press the highlighted button and the next random button should be highlighted and so on. I have successfully made same type of app for VR but here in MRTK, it is very hard to make button highlighted. I will be very thankful if someone help me with sample code.

I am attaching the view of my scene also. 
I have used the following code to highlight code in VR but how can i used that code in MRTK. It is not working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Randomcolor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9, BX, ST;
    public static int r, r_prev;

    void Start()
    {
        B1 = GameObject.Find("Button1");
        B2 = GameObject.Find("Button2");
        B3 = GameObject.Find("Button3");
        B4 = GameObject.Find("Button4");
        B5 = GameObject.Find("Button5");
        B6 = GameObject.Find("Button6");
        B7 = GameObject.Find("Button7");
        B8 = GameObject.Find("Button8");
        B9 = GameObject.Find("Button9");
        ST = GameObject.Find("ButtonSRT");

        B1.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B2.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B3.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B4.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B5.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B6.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B7.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B8.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        B9.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
    }

    public void clickB1()
    {
        Color_Highlight();
    }

    public void Color_Highlight()
    {
        System.Random random_number = new System.Random();
        r = random_number.Next(9) + 1;
        while (r == r_prev)
        {
             r = random_number.Next(9) + 1;
         }
        r_prev = r;

        if (r == 1) { BX = B1; }
        if (r == 2) { BX = B2; }
        if (r == 3) { BX = B3; }
        if (r == 4) { BX = B4; }
        if (r == 5) { BX = B5; }
        if (r == 6) { BX = B6; }
        if (r == 7) { BX = B7; }
        if (r == 8) { BX = B8; }
        if (r == 9) { BX = B9; }

        var colors = BX.GetComponent<Button>().colors;
        colors.normalColor = Color.cyan;
        BX.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colors;
    }

    public void Color_Reset()
    {
        var colors = BX.GetComponent<Button>().colors;
        colors.normalColor = new Color32(69, 154, 43, 255);
        BX.GetComponent<Button>().colors = colors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We saw that you modified the `normalColor` of the button in the code, so the corresponding property in MRTK Control may be what you expect. The [Interactable](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html) script is the right direction and your screenshot shows that it has been added to the button.

Actually, in MRTKv2, [States](http://%20https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html#how-to-configure-interactable) in the Interactable components define the interaction phases, like press or observed and the [`DefaultInteractableStates`](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_release/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Interactable/States/DefaultInteractableStates.asset) ships with MRTK out-of-box contains four states: Default, Focus, Press, Disabled. Visual Themes will response to these state transitions. It may involve changing a button's color, resizing an element in response to focus, etc.

So, to change the Default color of the MRTK button control base on your existing code logic, the color property you need to modify is in the default state of the theme that applies in the Interactable component.

Taking InteractablesExamples scene in MixedRealityToolkit.Examples/Demos/UX/Interactables/Scenes as an example, the following code is the easiest way to change the color of the HolographicButton object that in the Default state:

```
var colorTheme = this.GetComponent<Interactable>().ActiveThemes[0];
colorTheme.StateProperties[0].Values[0].Color = Color.green;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am just stucked at this from several days. You are only one to reply me. I tried by applying your suggestion but now not even playing by giving the following error. I can change the whole button structure and code if there is a simple way to do this. kindly suggest me. ' NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Timer.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Timer.cs:37) ' @Hernando-MSFT

Comment: You need to research these two documents(https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html & https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/VisualThemes.html) and configure your interactable component correctly, after which you can modify the color of the theme in the code. Besides, the InteractablesExamples scene provided by the MRTKv2 is an excellent outset to become familiar with Interactable components. So, it is strongly recommended that you refer to this sample to fix your project. The above code is also based on the sample.